How to iterate inputs depending on contents of separate list
I have 2 functions. My goal is to ask the user to connect some cables which are pre defined (according to the specific test they are running), confirm they have done this, then ask the user to confirm which COMPorts they wish to use.
My issue (located in the define_ports() function) is is that I would like to know how to dynamically spit out inputs for the user, depending on how many cable connections I have previously defined. Apologies if this is simple, it's been a long day and my brain isn't working right now.
Code below:
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
conec1 = 'USB Captive Cable'
conec2 = 'Serial RS232 Cable'
conec3 = None
cons = [conec1, conec2, conec3]
spar = 0
conec_list = []
for i in cons:
    if i != None:
        conec_list.append(i) 
        spar += 1

def Setup():
    def test_setup(conec1, conec2, conec3):
        "Details what cables need to be connected before test can progress"
        print('\n> > For this test you will need to connect the following:\n')
        for i in conec_list:
            if i != None:
                print(i)
        while True:
            yes = input('> > Please confirm this has been done. y/n ')
            if yes != 'y':
                continue
            else:
                break
        return conec1, conec2, conec3

    def define_ports():
        "Asks user to confrim which Port numbers are to be used for each port connection"
        test_setup(conec1, conec2, conec3)
        print('\n> > The available Port connections are: ')
        for p in ports:
            print(p)
        while True:
            print('\n> > Please confirm which Port numbers are to be used for each connection\n')
            global prt1
            global prt2
            global prt3
            
            for i in conec_list:
                if i != None:
                    prt1 = input(f'- Port number for {conec1}: ')
                    prt2 = input(f'- Port number for {conec2}: ')
                    prt3 = input(f'- Port number for {conec3}: ')
            
            print('\n> > The Port numbers you have selected are: '
                f'{conec1} = {prt1}, '
                f'{conec2} = {prt2}'
                f'{conec3} = {prt3}')

            flash = input('Is this correct? y/n ')
            if flash != 'y':
                continue
            else:
                break
        prt1 = str('COM'+prt1)
        prt2 = str('COM'+prt2)
        prt3 = str('COM'+prt3)
        
    define_ports()

Setup()

The issue i'm running into at the minute is getting the inputs (prt1, prt2, prt3) to be presented to the user depending on how many items there are in conec_list. I have tried various for loops but am not sure if this is the best way to try.

Avoid all those numeric variables. Just uses lists for everything. Then you can just use loops to collect all the inputs into another list: ports = [input(f'- Port number for {conec}') for conec in conec_list]

What is the output you are expecting to get and what does the current program yield? Sorry to say but your script structure is rather bizarre and it is not quite obvious what the problem is versus what is the expected output.

You can dynamically iterate over conec_list and collect the user's port inputs based on the number of cables. Instead of hardcoding prt1, prt2, and prt3, you can use a dictionary or a list to store the port numbers.
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
conec1 = 'USB Captive Cable'
conec2 = 'Serial RS232 Cable'
conec3 = None
cons = [conec1, conec2, conec3]
spar = 0
conec_list = []
for i in cons:
    if i != None:
        conec_list.append(i) 
        spar += 1

def Setup():
    def test_setup(conec_list):
        """Details what cables need to be connected before test can progress"""
        print('\n> > For this test you will need to connect the following:\n')
        for i in conec_list:
            if i != None:
                print(i)
        while True:
            yes = input('> > Please confirm this has been done. y/n ')
            if yes != 'y':
                continue
            else:
                break

        return conec_list

    def define_ports(conec_list):
        """Asks user to confirm which Port numbers are to be used for each port connection"""
        test_setup(conec_list)

        print('\n> > The available Port connections are: ')
        for p in ports:
            print(p)

        port_dict = {}
        while True:
            print('\n> > Please confirm which Port numbers are to be used for each connection\n')

            # Dynamically ask for the port number for each cable in the conec_list
            for cable in conec_list:
                port_num = input(f'- Port number for {cable}: ')
                port_dict[cable] = 'COM' + port_num

            print('\n> > The Port numbers you have selected are:')
            for cable, port in port_dict.items():
                print(f'{cable} = {port}')

            flash = input('Is this correct? y/n ')
            if flash.lower() != 'y':
                continue
            else:
                break

        return port_dict

    ports_used = define_ports(conec_list)
    print("\nPorts to be used:", ports_used)

Setup()

I hope this will help you a little.

You can try modifying setup function like this
def Setup():
    "Details what cables need to be connected before test can progress"
    for i in conec_list:
        if i != None:
            print(i)
            yes = input('> > Please confirm this has been done. y/n ')

            if yes != 'Y' or yes != 'y':
                print("Exiting program")
                return "Try again"
    print('\n> > The available Port connections are: ')
    for p in ports:
        print(p)

    ports = []
    for i in conec_list:
        if i != None:
            prt = input(f'- Port number for {i}: ')
            ports.append([i,prt])

    for i in ports:
        print("Port number for {i[0]}: {i[1]}")
    
    flash = input('Is this correct? y/n ')

    if flash == "y" or flash == "Y":
        return "success"
    else:
        return "Failure"

print(Setup())


